# How to create, call a pipe?

Tags: c#

How can I create a pipe in C#, and how can I call the created pipe from another process?

Comment: Have you tried to look this up anywhere else or tried any other code?

Comment: I've used google but I've found only c++ examples and since I've never used pipes I couldn't find a good example to follow

Comment: I've used google but I've found only c++ examples and since I've never used pipes I couldn't find a good example to follow because I found only some parts of codes combined with c++ and java

Comment: @Jax What type of pipe are you looking for? Give more details; as currently written, this question is very vague

Comment: really?  google "c# pipes" yields a pile of good tutorials https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+pipes

Comment: @Jax the forth result on my google search of "c# create named pipe" yielded this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx Google can help :)

Comment: @Jax well, Reed gave you an awesome answer, I suggest you use and accept that then go and learn :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) to create a pipe in C#.  The MSDN documentation shows an example of usage, as well as this [MSDN Pipes Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx).

That being said, it's often easier to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) directly rather than making a pipe and managing it yourself.  WCF can use pipes as a transport mechanism, which dramatically simplifies both the creation, as well as the usage of the pipe.